# How to style blockquote?

Tags: line-spacing, quoting

I use this code:

```
\begin{quote}
my quote
\end{quote}
```

I want to set it to singlespacing although the rest of the text ist formated with oneandahalfspacing. i also want to set the font size. How can I do this?

Comment: What's the font size in the main document, and which font size do you want to use inside `quote` environments?

Comment: In the main text it is 12p and in the quote it should be 11p.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

(2021/06/22: I updated this answer in response to @moewe's very helpful comment, that some settings in the `lipsum` package changed since I posted this answer back in 2016. The update below consists  of adding a `\par` directive in the second argument of `\AtBeginEnvironment`. If you don't use the `lipsum` package, you probably don't need the added `\par` instruction.)

Assuming you use the [setspace](http://texcatalogue.ctan.org/entries/setspace.html) package and the instruction `\onehalfspacing` to modify the line spacing of the document, you may achieve your objective by including the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\par\singlespacing\small}
```

In the document classes I'm familiar with, if the main document font size is `12pt`, the instruction `\small` switches to `11pt` as the font size.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}   % for filler text
\usepackage{setspace} % for \onehalfspacing and \singlespacing macros
\onehalfspacing 

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\par\singlespacing\small}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]  % filler text
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: With a current LaTeX kernel this will also make the paragraph immediately preceding the `quote` environment single-spaced (actually I'm not sure if this is due to the recent change in the hook management: it could also be due to the fact that `\lipsum` no longer issues a `\par` at the end). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/569716/35864.

Comment: @moewe - Many thanks for bringing this issue to my attention. A quick (and hopefully-not-too-dirty) fix is to change `\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\singlespacing\small}` to `\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\par\singlespacing\small}`, i.e, to insert a `\par` directive. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Just for completeness: The change in behaviour is due to changes to `\lipsum`. Version 2.1 of `lipsum` released in 2018 no longer ends the output with `\par` (cf. https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.1629.1542704189.4481.ctan-ann@ctan.org). And indeed with the TeX Live 2017 available on Overleaf (where `\lipsum` ends with `\par`) things are alright, but with TeX Live 2018 on Overleaf (which has `lipsum` v2.2 where there is no `\par` at the end), the undesired effect can be observed.

Comment: @moewe - Thanks for your follow-up. I had been sort-of aware of the fact that the `lipsum` package had changed in recent years, but until just now I had never fully understood what was going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Since this is the first result I got when I Googled "latex block quote", I thought I'd mention the [`csquotes`](https://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package I found via [this Overleaf article](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Typesetting_quotations). Seems to do about the same thing, just not the font resizing the OP asked for.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{displayquote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{displayquote}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

... gets you this....

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can do that with the `etoolbox` package:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\singlespace\vspace{-\topsep}\small}
\AtEndEnvironment{quote}{\vspace{-\topsep}\endsinglespace}

\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{quote}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in [ahogen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/100076/ahogen)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/476650/35864), [`csquotes`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) is a great way to typeset all sorts of quotations.

One of the simplest ways to customise `csquotes`' block quotations is via `\SetBlockEnvironment` and a custom environment based on `quote`.

Unfortunately, we need to define a new helper command to enter singlespacing without space correction (`\singlespacingNoVspace`), since we already have enough space added by `quote`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\singlespacingNoVspace}{%
  \setstretch{\setspace@singlespace}}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{singlequote}
  {\quote\small\singlespacingNoVspace}
  {\endquote}

\SetBlockEnvironment{singlequote}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy lorem ipsum text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{displayquote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{displayquote}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: one-half spaced surrounding text, single-spaced quote]

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/602265/35864