# Typesetting block-quotations. Good practice?

Tags: formatting, csquotes

I am looking for a good practice in writing a phd dissertation document, in order to insert block-quotations from an interview inside my document in the results chapter. My solution, right now, is just to insert a `quotation` environment and to make typography small, with this MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{quotation}
    \small this is the quote
    \end{quotation}
\end{document}
```

In my case, in order to put texts from interviews I've done, is there any well-recommended quotation format? (typography size, spacing, etc...)

Comment: You should not do that. Your document should be clean. If you are only using quotations of this kind, your document should be like `\begin{quotation} this is the quote \end{quotation}` and then program the environment `quotation` to give the style you want. If you are having different “quotations”, you may want to define `interviewquote` for this particular use, and define others for other types, in case you want to differentiate them.

Comment: I don't think `\begin{quotation}...\end{quotation}` is the right approach with `csquotes`. You can customise the environment used by the `\blockquote` command from `csquotes`, rather than remembering to use `\small{}` all the time

Comment: Did you take a look at section 3.5, entitled "Block Quoting of Regular Text", of the user guide of the `csquotes` package?

Comment: Maybe something like this is useful http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325695/how-to-style-blockquote