# Excessive vertical space after quote using report class

Tags: spacing, etoolbox, report, vertical-spacing, quotation

I want to get rid of excessive vertical spacing after a block quote using the `report` class. I am using [this suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325698/265488) to customize the font size and spacing of the blockquote. It appears as if the last paragraph is forced to be aligned with the bottom of the page, and I would like to avoid that.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}   % for filler text
\usepackage{setspace} % for \onehalfspacing and \singlespacing macros
\onehalfspacing 

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\par\singlespacing\small}

\begin{document}
\section{Some title}
\lipsum[2]  % filler text
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[5]
\section{Another title}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: example of excessive vertical space after quote]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The new section probably won't fit at the bottom of the page, so it goes to the next.  If you don't mind having the bottoms of the pages ending at different locations, you can add `\raggedbottom` to allow that.

Comment: You're being unlucky: the section title must be followed by at least two lines to be printed at the bottom of a page. This is not the case here. Forget about the problem until your text is in final form; at that point there are several strategies available, including `\enlargethispage`.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the preamble this way:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\onehalfspacing}
\AtEndEnvironment{quote}{\onehalfspacing} % <--- added
```